# Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "datum" is null of string in field 'schemaVersionId' - Confluent Schema Registry

Tags: scala, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have an avro schema for which I am generating the Java bean using the `avro-maven-plugin`. I am then instantiating it and sending it to Kafka using also Confluent's Schema Registry. I can also consume and deserialise the avro into a Spark DataFrame just fine. The problem I am facing is that it is forcing me to set the `schemaVersionId` at the producer level. If I don't set it, the `KafkaAvroSerializer` will throw the error in the title. Any ideas please?

```
val contractEvent: ContractEvent = new ContractEvent()
contractEvent.setSchemaVersionId("1") // This should be appended as the schema is auto-registered.
contractEvent.setIngestedAt("123")
contractEvent.setChangeType(changeTypeEnum.U)
contractEvent.setServiceName("Contract")
contractEvent.setPayload(avroContract)
```

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "xxxxxxx",
  "name": "ContractEvent",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "ingestedAt", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "eventType",
      "type": {
        "name": "eventTypeEnum",
        "type": "enum", "symbols" : ["U", "D", "B"]
      }
    },
    {"name": "serviceName", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "payload",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Contract",
        "fields": [
          {"name": "identifier", "type": "string"},
          {"name": "createdBy", "type": "string"},
          {"name": "createdDate", "type": "string"},
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't use Scala, but `setSchemaVersionId` is not a method I have seen the Avro Maven Plugin add... And it is not required by Confluent Serializer... Can you show the actual stacktrace you get?

Comment: This error usually occurs with AWS Kafka serializer when you fail to provide a value for a mandatory field which has no default defined in the schema. I suspect that the actual Avro schema registered in your Glue registry (as well as the generated Java class) contains a mandatory `schemaVersionId` field.